# Winform DataGRidView Scroll Bar not showing until needed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a (Winforms) DataGridView and I want the vertical scroll bar to be viewable even when it is not yet required. Currently, if the number of rows in the DGV do not exceed the height of the DGV there is no vertical scroll bar:

[image]

When more rows are then added the scrollbar makes an appearance but seems to cover part of the last column:

[image]

I haven't been able to find anything on this specific circumstance online but am hoping someone out thee knows what is going on and advise if I am able to have the scroll bar show (albeit disabled??) even when it is not yet needed.